# Is it possible to retrieve custom property from AD using ADVAPI

Tags: java, active-directory, kerberos, jna, ntlm

I am doing NTLM/Kerberos SSO using `com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Sspi`, `com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Secur32` and `com.sun.jna.platform.win32.AdvapiUtils` to actually authenticate the user against the AD and retrieve its username. This works perfectly for both domain and non-domain users. As a next step I would like to retrieve a custom user property from the AD, e.g. email. Unfortunately, the `com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util.Account` class has only fqn, sid and groups properties. Is it possible using the native interfaces listed above to retrieve other properties as well?

I can't use LDAP because of a number of constraints, so I am looking for a work around.

Comment: Basically, I have the access token and would like to use it in some way to access the AD user object attributes.

Comment: did you get it working? or any suggested workaround?